# Is there a limit on IN clause for netezza tables?

Tags: sql, netezza

```
create table accounts as
select account_name, count(company) from tmp_table
where account_name in (select account_name from test_accounts)
group by account_name;

select * from accounts;
```

This query only fetches 12 records whereas it should have been 50 in my case, because there are 50 records in test_accounts.

I tried multiple things.

```
create table accounts as
select account_name, count(company) from tmp_table
where account_name in (list the name of all accounts in test_accounts)
group by account_name;

create table accounts as
select account_name, count(company) from tmp_table
where (added every account name in test_accounts with an OR clause)
group by account_name;
```

In all cases, I just got 12 records.

If I query tmp_table they are all there.

What did I miss?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I know this might be some stupid questions, but are there actually 50 different account_names in test_accounts? Do all values have an actual match in tmp_table? Are the datatypes for both columns the same? Which values are missing? What if you remove the COUNT/GROUP?

Comment: Answer to all your questions are, all of these have been verified.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following.  Depending on the datatypes of account_name I would also consider converting all the data to the same case using a `upper` or `lower` if it isn't an issue of case then I would suspect that you have spaces or other characters which need to be trimmed.

```
select ta.account_name
,nvl(tt.account_name,'No Match Found') as tmp_tbl_acct_nm
, count(tt.company) from (select account_name from test_accounts) ta  left outer join
 tmp_table tt
on trim(both from lower(ta.account_name))=trim(both from lower(tt.test_accounts))
group by ta.account_name,nvl(tt.account_name,'No Match Found');
```

Comment: case is already tested. I should try the trimming. Thanks for the suggestion.